# Error con Spatie y @can

Tags: php, html, laravel, spatie

Recien empiezo a trabajar con este complemento para mi proyecto, cree los seeders para poder insertar roles y permisos, cree usuarios y les asigné un rol para poder testear(Estoy usando la misma tabla users de laravel que viene por defecto, con la excepción de que he borrado el campo 'name'). El problema viene al usar dentro de mi archivo .blade.php el @can('nombre_del_permiso'), este me salta un error que no logro solucionar, espero puedan ayudarme.

El error en cuestión dice:
Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::Spatie\Permission{closure}(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable, App\Models\User given, called in C:\laragon\www\programasgto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 552

Inserto documentos:
Seeder de permisos

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //Crea aca los roles gg
        $rolAdmin = Role::create(['name' => 'Admin',]);
        $rolFunc = Role::create(['name' => 'Funcionario',]);
        $rolVisor = Role::create(['name' => 'Visor',]);

        //Crea los permisos de las dependencias
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.dependencias'])->syncRoles([$rolAdmin, $rolFunc]);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.dependencias.form'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.dependencias.edit'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.dependencias.delete'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);

        //Crea los permisos de los usuarios
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.usuarios'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.usuarios.form'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.usuarios.edit'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.usuarios.delete'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);

        //Crea los permisos de los programas
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.programas'])->syncRoles([$rolAdmin, $rolFunc]);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.programas.form'])->syncRoles([$rolAdmin, $rolFunc]);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.programas.edit'])->syncRoles([$rolAdmin, $rolFunc]);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'panel.programas.delete'])->assignRole($rolAdmin);
    }
}
```

User seeder:

```
public function run()
    {
        User::create([
            'email' => 'correo@correo.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('123456')
        ])->assignRole('Admin');
    }
```

Y por último, la línea que hasta donde entiendo, da error:

```
@can('panel.dependencias')
      <h1>Verificado</h1>
@endcan
```

Comment: segun el error spati esperaba un objeto de tipo Authorizable y tu le mandaste un objeto de tipo User; valida que te hace falta...

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que hay que hacer es editar el modelo ***User*** y añadir el ***trait*** `Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles` y extender ***Authenticatable*** (por defecto viene *Model*)

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    // ...
}
```